# adding custom type of number to a contact [Android]

Tags: android, android-contacts

I been working on an app that helps sending sms to your contacts. Everything is great, except that I'm supposed to add a "custom field number" to a contact such as "Work" or "Private". I'd search the web for answers and the ones that are useful for evryone, aren't for me. This is my code:

```
private void AddCtxtAttribute(int contactID, String contactNumber) {

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI);

    builder.withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactID);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, contactNumber);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "My Custom Label");

    ops.add(builder.build());

    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
        Log.e("RESULT", "Success! " + contactID + " - "
                + contactNumber);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR", "error : " + e.toString());
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ERROR", "error : " + e.toString());
    }

}
```

And it's called:

```
AddCtxtAttribute(contacto_id, contacto_numero);
```

where contacto_id and contacto_numero are a int and a String respectively.

The problem is that when I pressed the button, I have the ID (contacto_id) of that contact but it updates other contact. (like the id's don't match) but i've debug it and the id doesn't change.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!

the problem was that i was using diferent column names and uris in reading the contacts and inserting a new contact number.

I did this:
to query all contacts:

```
private void llenar_contactos() {

    ProgressDialog progress;
    lista_contactos_cel_sobrantes = null;

    sobrantes = false;

    lista_contactos_cel = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    progress = ProgressDialog.show(contactsActivity.this, "",
            "Cargando Contactos. Porfavor espere...");

    String[] projection = new String[] { Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.LABEL };

    String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

    // ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "='1'";
    String sort_order = "display_name ASC";

    Uri mContacts = Data.CONTENT_URI;
    // ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(mContacts, // Contact URI
            projection, // Which columns to return
            selection, // Which rows to return
            null, // Where clause parameters
            sort_order // Order by clause
            );

    total_contactos = contacts.getCount();

    if (total_contactos > 0) {

        int i = 0;

        int multiplo = 0;
        int indice_total = 0;

        int temp_registros = 0;

        String contact_id = "";
        String name = "";
        String phoneNo = "";
        String label = "";
        sobrantes = false;

        int nameFieldColumnIndex = 0;

        while (contacts.moveToNext()) {
            nameFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID);

            if (nameFieldColumnIndex > -1) {
                contact_id = contacts.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
            }

            nameFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

            if (nameFieldColumnIndex > -1) {
                name = contacts.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
            }

            nameFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

            if (nameFieldColumnIndex > -1) {
                phoneNo = contacts.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
            }

            nameFieldColumnIndex = contacts.getColumnIndex(Phone.LABEL);

            if (nameFieldColumnIndex > -1) {
                label = contacts.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
            }

            if(label != null){
                Log.i("CONTACTO", "id: " + contact_id + " -> name: " + name
                        + " ->number: " + phoneNo + " ->label: " + label);
            } else {
                Log.d("CONTACTO", "id: " + contact_id + " -> name: " + name
                        + " ->number: " + phoneNo + " ->label: " + label);
            }               


        }
        contacts.close();
    }
}
```

And to insert a new custom label:

```
private void AddCtxtAttribute(int contactID, String contactNumber) {

    if (contactID != 0 && contactNumber != null) {

         ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
              new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

     ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
              .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactID)
              .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
              .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, contactNumber)
              .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
              .withValue(Phone.LABEL, "My Custom Label")
              .build());
     try{
         getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);           
     } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```